# How to pass a json to a serializer to store in model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, serialization

my record/model.py is,

```
class HistoricalRecords(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    torque = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    car = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

my record/serializer.py is

```
class SaveAuditRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HistoricalRecords
        fields = ('user', 'role', 'model', 'torque', 'car', 'date_time')
```

and my record/views.py is,

```
def AuditRecord(request):

    serializer = SaveAuditRecordSerializer(data=request, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I am trying to call this `AuditRecord(req)` from another view of another app, like

```
rec = {}
audit_record['user'] = request.user
audit_record['role'] = "Role"
audit_record['model'] = "M"
audit_record['torque'] = 22222
audit_record['action'] = "car created"
audit_record['date_time'] = datetime.now()
AuditRecord(audit_record)
```

I dont get any error but it is not getting saved to db
is there any mistake in my approch?

Comment: Why are you doing that? Why don't you just create the record directly in that view, eg with `HistoricalRecords.objects.create(...)`?

Comment: inside record/views.py ?

Comment: In that "view of another app".

Comment: what modification should i do in this code to save data through serializer?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a model in your other app that points to your AuditRecord and you wanna create the record on it's create enpoint, you can use a serializer of this other app to create an instance of AuditRecord.

```
OtherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    audit_record = AuditRecordSerializer(required=False, write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        audit_record_data = validated_data.pop('audit_record')

        audit_record = AuditRecordSerializer().create(audit_record_data)
        validated_data.update({'audit_record': audit_record})

        return super(OtherSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```